# Can Spring Data Jpa Repository be used to create complex queries?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, left-join

First of all some context: i have 2 entities CommodityData(**commodityId**, code, defaultDescription) and CommodityDescription(**commodityId**, **lang**, description). The defaultDescription field in first table use english and the localizated description is in second table.

Using pure JPA i get what i need but *i would like to know if it is possible to implement it using SpringDataJpa Repository and Specifications* (**avoiding JPQL**).

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CommodityLang> query = cb.createQuery(CommodityLang.class);
Root<CommodityData> commodity = query.from(CommodityData.class);
Join<CommodityData, CommodityDescription> join = commodity.join("descriptions", JoinType.LEFT);
join.on(cb.equal(join.get("lang"), lang));
query.select(
        cb.construct(CommodityLang.class, 
                commodity.get("categoryId"), 
                commodity.get("code"), 
                commodity.get("parent"), 
                commodity.get("path"), 
                commodity.get("defaultDescription"), 
                commodity.get("legacyLink"),
                commodity.get("documentId"), 
                commodity.get("type"), 
                commodity.get("status"), 
                join.get("description"), 
                join.get("lang")
        ));

TypedQuery<CommodityLang> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);

List<CommodityLang> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The use of Spring Data Repository would be interesting because it would avoid handling pagination and sorting, but reading the source of SimpleJpaRepository I think it's not possible. It's correct?

Thank you,
Gabriele

PS: Left join use a **on** condition to do some filter on records.

Comment: For some complex queries, you can use native query !

Comment: By "pure JPA" you mean the criteria API? Why do you want to avoid JPQL? Why do you want it to use `Specification` and not say a `@Query` annotation?

Comment: @TinyOS: i try to avoid native query to preserve database abstraction (i know that Is not always possibile).

Comment: @Jens: yes, i meant Criteria API. In my service layer normally i pass to repository two objects (CommonSpecification, Pageble). The First Is my own Class that loop on a roles Array (a list of "field, operator, value" that arrived as JSON from frontend) and generate the right predicate. To preserve this structure i would like (if It Is possibile) use ```Specification``` instead of ```@Query```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one year of development we have come to a compromise.

With JPA we have made even custom repositories very complex but we have found that over time they are not very maintainable and you cannot do a great optimization.

For CRUD operations we use SpringData over JPA, for complex report we use MyBatis that allows us to tune queries.

With a similar stack so i suggest to use this combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine repositories and specifications:

```
 UserSpecification useSpecification = 
  new UserSpecification(new SearchCriteria("lastname", ":", "Trump"));

List<User> results = repository.findAll(useSpecification);
```

You also get paging, [look at this example](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Comment: thank you but in this case i've a ```left join``` with ```on``` clause and don't know how combine this with specification/repository.